# How to let resize and also give margin for whole screen in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

I want to give a margin around the whole screen in Flutter. So I put my content inside a Column and put the Column inside a Container. So I gave a padding to the whole screen. But when a TextField is selected and the keyboard appears the bottom overflow. I can't give resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false, because then the keyboard covers the TextField.
I can't use SingleChildScrollView or a ListView because then the placing of the children won't keep space between.
It seems the only option is to remove the Container and set a padding to each child of the Column.
Is there a better option for this ?

Comment: You should SingleChildScrollView as a parent view of the Container which Column inside a Container. like SingleChildScrollView(Container(Column))

Comment: Then the Column won't keep the space between.

Comment: It will keep the space between just use Expanded() into the Column.

Comment: If device screen is smaller than the height of widgets, I don't want to keep space in between. So it will be scrollable also. But if the screen is bigger, it has to keep the space before the bottom button.

Comment: Didn't get your query, can you please provide the Screenshots and Code.